# Does Dojo have anything like jQuery's :has() selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dojo

Does Dojo have anything like [jQuery's :has() selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)?

Comment: dojo has has but idk working is same http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/has.html

Comment: No it's pretty obviously different.

Comment: @Daniel: Note that `:has()` is not a CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo, does not support this directly.  It has native support for two different selector engines: acme & lite (see documentation for [dojo/query](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html#selector-engines)).  Lite is intended to be fast and efficient but lacking some of the advanced (but rarely used features).  Acme is a fully-featured CSS3 selector.

You can also load 3rd-party engines as plugins; including the [Sizzle engine](http://sizzlejs.com/) used by jQuery.  By using Sizzle you then have access to the **:has()** selector  in your queries.

This can be done, either in the main Dojo config or on-the-fly as a plugin:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    /*
        This change the selector engine globally within Dojo.  Be careful
        that this does not adversely affect any loaded modules, which
        use dojo/query
    */

    "selectorEngine": "sizzle/sizzle"
};
```

or:

```
require([
    "dojo/query!sizzle/sizzle"
], function($){
    var divs = $("div:has(p)");
});
```

Since Sizzle is not part of the Dojo core, you will need to download and install it into the sizzle directory next to dojo, dojox, dijit for this to work.  (Also, see: [dojo/query (alternative selectors)](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html#alternate-selector-engines) & [Sizzle engine](http://sizzlejs.com/)).

Unless this is a must-have feature, it's probably better to use the native selector.  However, Dojo is designed with maximum flexibility.